# Change Background for all MetroWindow (MahApp)

Tags: wpf, xaml, background, mahapps.metro

I've just started using MahApps with WPF. I would like to change background color of all MetroWindow. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745367/change-background-in-metrowindow-mahapp) indicates how to do it for one instance of a MetroWindow, but is there a way to override the default background color for this control type?

I would expect to be able to change it by customizing a Mahapps theme. I created a custom theme (copied from BaseDark.xaml), changed all SolidColorBrush values, applied the theme in the OnStartup event using "ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle" but the MetroWindow background didn't change.

This code (put in the App.xaml) doesn't work either:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}}" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
</Style>
```

In addition to MetroWindow, I would also like to override the background color of the System.Windows.Controls.UserControl type.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Color in the Mahapps theme that change the MetroWindow background color:

```
<Color x:Key="WhiteColor">#FF373F44</Color>
```